# SSL error : Secure Connection Failed

Tags: php, wordpress, security, ssl, https

I purchased a SSL certificate that will expire in 2019 , Then I installed it and now it's doing well on Chrome and showing green Padlock.

But on Mozilla Firefox, I get an error:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection. Peer’s Certificate has been revoked.
Error code: SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE
```

I searched for an answer and viewed some questions about it here , But didn't find a solution.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

How is it possible to be secured on a browser and not on another?

Website : https://masteryourlifepower.com

Comment: Even if the certificate is valid when you look at it, browsers take the certificate and validate with the Certificate Authority signer if it is valid, and has not been revoked.  I have had the same problem in the past, we had purchased a certificate for 3 years, but on a yearly payment plan.  So the certificate was issued with 3 years of validity, but we forgot to pay after the 1st year was done.  The signer revoked it.  So 1- check the dates on the certificate.  2- check the dates on the signer certificates (some CA change those).  3- check revocation status.

Comment: 4- check if the signer is in the recognized signers for Firefox.  It might be ok for Chrome, but not for Firefox.

Comment: @Nic3500 , How to get the signers and see if it's recognized?

Comment: Browsers differ if and how they check for revocation (see https://scotthelme.co.uk/certificate-revocation-google-chrome/ for some details). If the certificate was revoked it might be that one browser finds out about this while  another does not. It might of course also be a bug or you might inadvertently use a different URL when testing with different certificates behind it (i.e. example.com vs. www.example.com). It would be helpful if you would provide a way for others to reproduce your problem, i.e. publish the URL where the certificate is installed on.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , I updated the question and added the website URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Website : https://masteryourlifepower.com

The [report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=masteryourlifepower.com&latest) clearly shows that the certificate was revoked, thus Firefox is complaining correctly:

```
Revocation status   Revoked   INSECURE
```

> How is it possible to be secured on a browser and not on another?

Browser check in different ways for revocation or might check not at all. The old was was to use [CRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list) which did not scale. The modern way is to use [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) which requires the OCSP server of the CA to be always reachable and also might slow down the connection establishment unless OCSP stapling is used. Therefore Chrome uses [CRLSets](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55811/how-are-crlsets-more-secure) which contains only the revoked certificates Google considers relevant.

In your specific case the certificate is revoked. Firefox probably used OCSP to check for it and successfully detected the revocation. Chrome used CRLSets and since your site was not deemed important enough Google did not include the revocation into the CRLSets and thus the revocation was not detected.

Comment: So the reason it's showing this error on Mozilla is that it's revoked or it can't find OCSP?

Comment: @Bon:  the error message from Firefox you cite clearly says the reason: *"Peer’s Certificate has been revoked."*

Answer (score 0):

I was lifting Wordpress backup and got this line "Secure Connection Failed".
These errors were due to plugins requiring SSL certificates such as Google analytics.
after removing the plug-ins, everything worked.